Why am I receiving duplicate push notifications in both PWA and Chrome browser?
I am developing a PWA that uses Push Notifications. The issue I am facing is that when a push notification is sent from the server, the user receives it twice:
Once in the PWA.
Once again in the Chrome browser.
I expect the notification to appear only once.
Here’s the code I’m using in the service worker to handle push events:
const beamsClient = new PusherPushNotifications.Client({
    instanceId: 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx-xxxx',
});

beamsClient.start()
    .then(() => beamsClient.addDeviceInterest('user-123'))
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered and subscribed!'))
    .catch(console.error);

And here’s how I’m registering the service worker:
importScripts('https://js.pusher.com/beams/service-worker.js');

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    if (!event.data) {
        console.error('No payload received');
        return;
    }

    const data = event.data.json();
    const options = {
        body: data.body,
        icon: data.icon || '/icon.png',
        badge: data.badge || '/badge.png',
        tag: data.tag || 'notification-tag', 
    };


    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options)
    );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow(event.notification.data?.url || '/')
    );
});

The server is correctly sending the notifications, and I’m confident that the issue is not on the server side.
How can I prevent duplicate notifications from being shown by both the PWA and the Chrome browser?
If more details are needed, let me know.
Thanks in advance for your help!

The issue may be that you are registering the push notification when the page is first loaded as a non-PWA, i.e. before the user installs as PWA. So, now the push is registered in non-PWA and PWA. The solution would be to NOT register the push notification unless the "app" is running as a PWA.
